# PKPaymentAuthorizationController is not presented sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, applepay, passkit

We ran into a problem that the `PKPaymentAuthorizationController` is not presented, although everything is done, as described in the examples. A `PKPaymentRequest` is created in the code, passed to the `PKPaymentAuthorizationController` initializer, after which the `present` method is called on this `PKPaymentAuthorizationController` as well. This behavior is reproduced steely the first time you try to show the controller in a freshly installed application. Also, the bug can be reproduced randomly during the subsequent use of the application; in this case, it is impossible to find any explicit way of reproducing.
The issue is definitely not a typo in any of the values ​​required to create the `PKPaymentRequest`, I mean `merchantIdentifier`, `supportedNetworks`, `merchantCapabilities`, `countryCode`, `currencyCode` and `paymentSummaryItems`, we have already checked this more than once. The issue is also not about converting a `Double` price value into `NSDecimalNumber`, as was written in one of the answers to a similar question on Stack Overflow. We used the debugger, which showed that the `PKPaymentRequest` is successfully created, just like the `PKPaymentAuthorizationController` itself. But when the `present` method is called, nothing happens on the screen. We would be grateful if you could help us solve the issue. Here is a sample code:

```
        let request = PKPaymentRequest()
        request.merchantIdentifier = "HERE_IS_OUR_M_ID"
        request.supportedNetworks = [.amex, .visa, .masterCard]
        request.merchantCapabilities = .capability3DS
        request.countryCode = "US"
        request.currencyCode = "USD"
        request.paymentSummaryItems = [
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "BUY_ITEM_TEXT", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: buyItemPrice)),
            PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "COMPANY_NAME", amount: NSDecimalNumber(value: buyItemPrice), type: .final)
        ]
        let applePayController = PKPaymentAuthorizationController(paymentRequest: request)
        applePayController.delegate = self
        applePayController.present(completion: nil)
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @JeanAzzopardi Hello! Not yet :(

Comment: an idea that i've been playing around with is to automatically retry to show upon failure.. it has worked but it does add a bit of a delay. However, I'm very much aware that this is just a workaround.

Comment: @JeanAzzopardi we have tried smth similar, and faced the delay that you have mentioned. Seems that there is other way to resolve it.

Comment: TonyMit @jean-azzopardi one more with the same issue here! Did you manage to find a working solution, or just used the workaround?